# How to make index() method return an integer instead of None?

Tags: python

I am trying to return the index value of the first vowel in a string using these functions:

```
def is_vowel(c):
    v = 'aeiou'
    for l in v:
        if l == c:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def index_of_first_vowel(string):
    for l in string:
        if is_vowel(l):
            index = int(string.index(l))
            return index
```

So the string 'hello' should return 1.

I have tried many different ways of writing the second function and every time it returns `None`.
Am I using the `index()` method correctly? Or is my logic off somewhere?

Comment: Have you tested your `is_vowel`? function? You should.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: the is_vowel function returns true if a letter is a vowel and false otherwise. is that where the problem is?

Comment: The problem is that it *doesn't* do this. What do you get when you print `is_vowel('e')`?

Comment: You should also read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: omg i was only testing it with 'a', lmao ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem, you don't need to loop in the list of letters in the function is_vowel, you can just look if c is in it.

Also, your loop would be interrupted at the first pass every time you don't pass an 'a'

```
>>> def is_vowel(c):
...     if c in "aeiou":
...             return True
...     return False
... 
>>> def index_of_first_vowel(string):
...     for l in string:
...             if is_vowel(l):
...                     index = int(string.index(l))
...                     return index
... 
>>> print(index_of_first_vowel("hello"))
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your approach can be improved quite a bit:

- The whole `is_vowel()` can be rewritten in one line (and considering also the case):

```
def is_vowel(c):
    return c in 'aeiouAEIOU'
```

and that can be easily inlined.

- Instead of using `str.index()`, you can just keep track of the index at each iteration. The idiomatic way in Python is by using `enumerate()`.
- If you do not want your function to return `None`, you have to explicitly use `return` after your loop to handle the case of no character actually being a vowel.
- The code can be made more general by inputing the "vowel" definition as a paremeter.

Putting all these together, one gets:

```
def find_any(s, chars='aeiouAEIOU'):
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c in chars:
            return i
    return -1
```

---

For larger input strings, and small character sets a much more efficient approach is to use the `start` and `stop` parameters of [`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) or, possibly faster, [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) which does not require a `try`/`catch` to handle missing matches:

```
def find_any_other(s, chars='aeiouAEIOU'):
    result = -1
    for char in chars:
        idx = s.find(char, 0, result)
        if idx > 0:
            result = idx
        if not idx:
            break
    return result if result < len(s) else -1
```

A simple test to show the timings indicate that the second approach can be **much** faster:

```
n = 1
s = 'x' * n + 'hello'
%timeit find_any(s)
# 1.35 µs ± 174 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit find_any_other(s)
# 6.04 µs ± 332 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

n = 1000000
s = 'x' * n + 'hello'
%timeit find_any(s)
# 172 ms ± 6.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit find_any_other(s)
# 790 µs ± 36.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```